# Deploy JHipster Angular Client App to Apache Web Server

Tags: angular, jhipster

I created the JHipster project with the server and client separately. I created a war file for the server-side and deployed it to Tomcat. It works without any problem.
Then I built the client-side with `npm run webpack:build`. I copied all content of `build\resources\main\static`folder to the apache HTML folder.
When I try to run client-side it gives an error.

[image]

**What I am doing wrong? How to deploy JHipster angular app to Apache?**

Comment: Please edit your question with more details about your deployment because this is not the most usual way. What do you try to achieve? Are you using apache as reverse proxy 
 for backend to avoid CORS restrictions? What's the URI of you angular app bundle in apache? What error do you see in browser's console?

Answer (score 1):

I missed a simple thing. I didn't set `<base href="/"/>`